# Accurately number and count a file populated by multiple subprocesses

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I have a script that calls multiple instances of another script. These child processes all write in the same file, and I want an accurate method of counting and numbering the lines in that file.

These child processes also write their exit codes in a separate file when they are done, which is how I track them. The parent script has an "infinite" while loop that reads the file containing the exit codes until the number of lines = number of child script instances.

The idea is that the child processes unpredictably write "line" in the same file, "log.txt".

So what I tried was having each of them do a grep -c on the log.txt to check the current number of "line", and add one:

parent_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ ))
do
    child_script.sh
done

certain_check=0

while [[ `wc -l < exitfile.txt` -le 10 ]]; do
    if [[ `wc -l < exitfile.txt` -eq 10 ]]; then
        certain_check=$(( $certain_check + 1 ));
    fi
    [[ $certain_check -eq 2 ]] && break;
done
```

child_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i<=100; i++ ))
do
    if [[ ! -f log.txt ]]; then
        counter=1;
    else
        counter=$(( `grep -c "line" log.txt` + 1 ));
    fi
    echo $counter" line";
    echo $counter" line" >> log.txt;
    sleep 0.$RANDOM;
done
```

This worked decently, but every now and then it would use the same number twice in a row, probably due to the fact that two subprocesses are writing in the file at the same time. Afterwards, the "grep -c" would pick up the right amount of lines and correct itself in the long run.

Has anyone had to do something similar and perhaps had a better idea than me?
Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:** The scripts above are simplifications. The real child script is a job that through some other tools copies the schema of a table from a source database, creates it on a destination database, and transfers the data from the source table to the destination table through data streams (the databases are on different servers as well). The parent script just calls multiple instances and manages them so more tables can be processed at the same time.

This is why I want to display in real time both in terminal and in a file something like:

```
1) Loading table A
2) Loading table B
3) Loading table C
```

Each child script is given a list of tables as an argument, therefore each will process more tables, and depending on their size, one subprocess can process three tables while another isn't done with it's first yet.

The idea of having them numbered is to get an understanding of how many tables are left, as some jobs process even more than 2000 tables. Also I'm trying to avoid "waiting" mechanisms as these would affect the overall performance.

I hope these additional details take away some of the confusion!

Comment: While it's not clear what your end goal is, I have had similar situations and I would have had each child process write it's own log file (with a time stamp on the first column) and then as needed merge them together to "calculate" the final result. Each log file could contain other information that would help identify which sub-job was responsible for the record. That line of code `counter=$(( $(grep -c "line" log.txt) + 1 ));` makes for a very "expensive" logging process (IMHO). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your input! I tried to exclude as many details as I could in an attempt to simplify the matter, but I will add some more information as per what I would exactly like to achieve. The approach you took does not really work for what I would like to do though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I did not realise this at the time, my man @shellter had a *brilliant* idea. I solved this by having each child script write in it's own log file, thus avoiding the scenario when two instances are writing at the same time in the same file, and then I just keep on processing those files, one by one, line by line, checking for unnumbered lines, inside that "infinite while loop".

parent_script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=1; i<=10; i++ ))
do
    child_script.sh
done

certain_check=0
tbl_count=1;

while [[ `wc -l < exitfile.txt` -le 10 ]]; do
    for (( r=0; r<=9; r++ ))
    do
        [[ -f log$r.txt ]] && cat log$r.txt >> parent_log.txt && rm -f log$r.txt;
        if [[ -f parent_log.txt ]]; then
            while grep -q ^"Loading" parent_log.txt > /dev/null;
            do      
                a=`grep ^"Loading" parent_log.txt | head -1`;
                echo "${tbl_count}) $a
                ";
                sed "s/^$a/${tbl_count}) $a/" parent_log.txt > tmpfile.txt;
                cat tmpfile.txt > parent_log.txt;
                rm -f tmpfile.txt;
                tbl_count=$(( $tbl_count + 1 ));
            done
        fi
    done
    if [[ `wc -l < exitfile.txt` -eq 10 ]]; then
        certain_check=$(( $certain_check + 1 ));
    fi
    [[ $certain_check -eq 2 ]] && break;
done
```

The parent script creates directories for each child script, such as transfer0,transfer1, transfer2, etc. The instance number is extracted from the directory name in the child script:

child_script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ind=`pwd | sed 's|.*/\(.*\)|\1|' | sed 's/transfer\(.*\)/\1/'`;

for (( i=1; i<=100; i++ ))
do
    if [[ ! -f log.txt ]]; then
        counter=1;
    else
        counter=$(( `grep -c "line" log.txt` + 1 ));
    fi
    echo $counter" line";
    echo $counter" line" >> log$ind.txt;
    sleep 0.$RANDOM;
done
```

There's more to it in the actual scripts, obviously. But this is the main idea. Kudos to you, @shellter!